# Python Iterating through two lists only iterates through last element

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to iterate through a double list but am getting the incorrect results. I am trying to get the count of each element in the list.

```
l = [['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']]

dict = {}

for words in l:
    for letters in words:
        dict[letters] = words.count(letters)


for x in countVocabDict:
        print(x + ":" + str(countVocabDict[x]))
```

at the moment, I am getting:

```
<s>:1
a:1
b:2
c:2
</s>:1
```

It seems as if it is only iterating through the last list in `'l' : ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']`

but I am trying to get:

```
<s>: 3
a: 4
b: 5
c: 6
</s>:3
```

Comment: Minor comments, you shouldn't use 'l' as this an ambiguous variable name; and you shouldn't name dictionaries `dict` as this is a python type.

Comment: MCVE + attempt + "New contributor": cool!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In each inner `for` loop, you are not adding to the current value of `dict[letters]` but **set** it to whatever amount is counted for the current sublist (peculiarly) named `word`.

Fixing your code with a vanilla `dict`:

```
>>> l = [['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']]
>>> d = {}                                                                  
>>>
>>> for sublist in l: 
...:     for x in sublist: 
...:         d[x] = d.get(x, 0) + 1 
>>> d                                                                       
{'<s>': 3, 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, '</s>': 3}
```

Note that I am not calling `list.count` in each inner `for` loop. Calling `count` will iterate over the whole list again and again. It is far more efficient to just add `1` every time a value is seen, which can be done by looking at each element of the (sub)lists exactly once.

Using a `Counter`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter                                         
>>> Counter(x for sub in l for x in sub)                                    
Counter({'<s>': 3, 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, '</s>': 3})
```

Using a `Counter` and not manually unnesting the nested list:

```
>>> from collections import Counter                                         
>>> from itertools import chain                                        
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(l))                                         
Counter({'<s>': 3, 'a': 4, 'b': 5, 'c': 6, '</s>': 3})
```

Answer (score 1):

The dictionary is being overwritten in every iteration, rather it should update

```
count_dict[letters] += words.count(letters)
```

Initialize the dictionary with defaultdict

```
from collections import defaultdict
count_dict = defaultdict(int)
```

Comment: The key `letter` must be initialized in `dict` to prevent `KeyError`

Comment: @Bogdan I have updated the answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

As @Vishnudev said, you must add current counter. But `dict[letters]` must exists (else you'll get a `KeyError` Exception). You can use the `get` method of dict with a default value to avoir this:

```
l = [['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], 
     ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], 
     ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']]

dict = {}
for words in l:
    for letters in words:
        dict[letters] = dict.get(letters, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you seem to know that it only takes on the result of the last sublist. This happens because after every iteration your previous dictionary values are replaced and overwritten by the next iteration values. So, you need to maintain the previous states values and add it to the newly calculated values.

You can try this-

```
l = [['<s>', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'c', '</s>'], ['<s>', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'a', 'b', '</s>']]
d={}
for lis in l:
    for x in lis:
        if x in d:
            d[x]+=1
        else:
            d[x]=1
```

So the resulting dictionary d will be as-

```
{'<s>': 3, 'a': 4, 'c': 6, 'b': 5, '</s>': 3}
```

I hope this helps!